# laravel 5 - change label id though a foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a foreach loop that I want it to create some unique checkboxes. 
because I am hiding the checkbox and using label to check the checkbox (making checkbox as div) I want my checkbox to have a unique id with the label the same how can I achieve that ?? here is my code :

```php
@foreach($pdate as $pdates)
    <div  id="checkboxes" class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}" id="r1"/>
        <label class="whatever" for="r1"> {{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}
          <hr>
          {{$pdates->price}}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So here I want id and for to be `rl+1` and so on untill my foreach finishes.

Comment: better use the PK `id="rl_{{ $pdates->id }}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index like this:

```php
@foreach($pdate as $index => $pdates)
    <div  id="checkboxes" class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}" id="r{{$index}}"/>
        <label class="whatever" for="r1">
            {{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}
            <hr>
            {{$pdates->price}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So your checkboxes ids will be r0, r1, r2...

Comment: thanks its working now but i am a bi confused what is this $index what it does?? can u explain a bit or link the laravel documentation of it ??

Comment: 1 more question what if i wana $request->r{{$index}} it ??? i mean how to get that in controller ?

Comment: You can specify any array as key-value array in a foreach loop, if the keys are  not specific like `['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2' ]` the "default" keys will be the item position in the array. So `['one', 'two']` will be `[0 => 'one', 1 => 'two']`. In my answer I am accessing those keys for setting different values for the id field.

Comment: how about my next question in comment should i post it and you answer it ??

Comment: I am not exactly sure of what are you trying to achieve there, so yes please, if you don't mind elaborate it as a new question with an example.

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490344/how-to-receive-an-incremented-id-though-for-each-in-controller-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

You can use counter to make unique id like this:

```
<?php $counrer=1; ?>
@foreach($pdate as $pdates)
    <div  id="checkboxes" class="col-lg-2 text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}" id="r1{{$counter}}"/>
        <label class="whatever" for="r1"> {{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}
        <hr>
        {{$pdates->price}}</label>
    </div>
<?php  $counter++; ?>
@endforeach
```