# how to receive an incremented id though for each in controller laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i have a form that i increase the id of checkbox through a foreach with unknown size now when i submit i want to receive all of the sent data here is my code :

```
 <form action="/somecontroller" method="post">
                    <div  id="checkboxes" class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" name="d{{$index}}" value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}" id="d{{$index}}"/>
                        <label class="whatever mt-3" for="d{{$index}}"> {{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}
                            <hr>
                            {{$pdates->price}}</label>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

and here is the controller :

```
 $recived_data = $request->d{{$index}}; here i want to get all the checkboxes send by user
```

so how can i recive the data that user send which i dont know the number of checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array syntax of the input element, and receive the array with selected items in the controller, so change your input checkbox to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="d[{{$index}}]" value="{{verta($pdates->date)->format('Y/m/d')}}" id="d{{$index}}"/>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$request->input('d'); // returns an array of indexes of all the selected checkboxes.
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding :)